# Password management between ubuntu, iPhone and windows

Tags: password

I use Ubuntu, Windows, and have an iPhone.  I'm looking for a password management system that can sync passwords across all three of these platforms - anyone have any suggestions?

LastPass looks like it would work, but it is $17/year for the iPhone app - I'm not against paying something, but this seems high.

Another option I think could be Keepass, but there is no iPhone app so I guess I have to get an app that uses the same .kdb file format, and use iCloud/DropBox to somehow sync the .kdb file...?

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with "KeePass2", which has a Windows and Linux version.  On both OSes I also installed DropBox and got a free account.  I save the KeePass2 file in DropBox so it stays in sync between the two OSes.

On the iPhone I bought "KeePass Touch" for $1.39, which can sync up with DropBox.  I don't think I can write passwords for the iPhone -- just read them -- but that's not a huge deal.  (I also installed DropBox on the iPhone, but don't think I need to do that; I think it is built into KeePass touch).